# Show NSWindow when webview is loaded

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift

Is it possible to delay showing a NSWindow until the webview that it contains is fully loaded?

I am loading the files from the filesystem but you are still getting a flicker. I was wondering if I can somehow wait for the webview to load and only then the window to appear.

Comment: Just a thought, but where are you loading the view?  In the windowDidLoad method of the window's delegate?

Comment: the view is loaded automatically via a storyboard. One possible solution is set the alpha to 0 and once everything is ready set the animator proxy alpha to 1. This sort of works but then the behaviour of the window is not the same as the standard behaviour.

Comment: Using a xib file and creating your own window controller might give you a little more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Interface Builder (Attributes section) select window and uncheck Visible At Launch
2. To be notified when all the resources are done loading, use : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/webView:didFinishLoadForFrame:

   -(void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFinishLoadForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame { ... }
3. Inside the method use [windowController showWindow:nil]; to show window

Comment: Wow. This looks obvious. Thanks. I will try and report back.